# What is the purpose of holes in the sound box of a sonometer?

Tags: waves, experimental-physics, string

The following two images of Sonometer, a device used to study the laws of transverse vibrations of a string, show that the sound box (wooden part of the apparatus) consists of two or three holes:

[image]

<sup>Image Source: [Indosaw](http://www.indosawedu.com/sound-and-waves.php)</sup>

[image]

<sup>Image Cropped from: [Sonometer-MeitY OLabs (YouTube video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=veQ-LfJhfxM)</sup>

What is the purpose of these holes? I think the difference in the number of holes in the above two images is something to do with the length.

There was no information about this in my book, and the image sources. The same question has already been asked in Quora, but the [answer](https://qr.ae/Teft08) there seems to be incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically a string instrument which makes the holes similar to an instrument's [sound holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_hole).  The effect is to make the audio from the strings louder.

If the box were sealed, the vibrations set up by the string could be dampened by the pressure from the air inside.  The box can vibrate farther when the air is free to move in and out.